# Range has turned to a table and macro won't run

Tags: vba, excel

I have had to change the formatting on a spreadsheet and the range referred to below is now a table.

Since changing this, my macro reports "Method 'Sort' of object 'Range' failed".

I can't name the table directly as the code cycles through all sheets in a spreadsheet (except excluded) and new sheets will be added that I won't know the table name/number for.

How do I select the table (location B72:L86) and sort it by column I?

```
For Each wsSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   Select Case wsSheet.Name
    Case "Affiliates", "New Report", "Pasted Report", "New Month Or Client", "Set Up Data"
        'Do nothing.

    Case Else
        With wsSheet
    .Range("B72:L86").Sort Key1:=.Range("I72"), Order1:=xlDescending
        End With
End Select
```

Comment: It seems that Range is a table name. Can you try to use Range.Range instead?

Comment: is there only table per sheet?

Comment: yes just one per sheet

Comment: I believe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054767/4717755) can help set up your sort on the table. My suggestion is to convert your code to use the `ListObject` (i.e. your table) by name reference.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one table per sheet, you can use the `.ListObjects(*index*)` property to refer to it.

```
Dim lo as ListObject
With wsSheet
    For Each lo in .ListObjects
    lo.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(lo.Name & _
    "[[#All],[" & .Range("I72").value & "]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= xlDescending
    With lo.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Next    
End With
```

Comment: With this I get - "Subscript out of range" error msg?

Comment: It must not be in the first index position. I amended the code to make it loop through all of the list objects on the page, (should be only one) so you're not beholden to the actual index number.

Comment: The amended code comes back with the error "Object Required" - any ideas?

Comment: On any particular line?